# Can the same player check and after re-raise (do all-in) at river?

Tags: rules

There are only 2 players left on River.

Player 1 has the dealer button and player 2 on the left hand.

Player 2 checks, player 1 (dealer) raises.

The question is can player 2 say All-In (after they checked and the dealer raised)?

If the answer is Yes/No could you explain a bit why. Thanks

Comment: Just a clarification, if Player 2 checks, Player 1 (dealer) cannot raise because there is no bet to him/her - they can bet, but it is not a raise.

Comment: Check-raising is perfectly legal in all forms of poker except California lowball (and even then some places).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're referring to No Limit Texas Holden, the answer is yes. Player No.2 can go all-in in that situation.

To make things clear, Here are the three betting rules in no limit Texas Holden:

- Any player facing a bet at any stage of the hand can fold, call, raise, or go all in.
- Any player facing a check, or he's the first to act, can bet, go all in, check, or fold (usually nobody folds when a check is available)
- The betting round is considered complete when a caller puts the same amount of money that the first player to his left had previously put.

Answer (score 1):

After you have been raised (or simply a bet in front of you) you have three options every time:

- fold
- call
- raise

Check raise is very common play. You let an aggressive player put money in the pot rather than possibly slow them down with a bet.

No 1. opened the pot up for raises by putting in a raise/bet.

If your check is checked back around to you then you cannot raise.

Let's say 1 was the pre flop raiser and lead out every round.  You just checked and called.  If you hit on the river your best play it to check again and let them lead out.  The money they put in the pot is money in the pot.  They are more likely to call an all in due to pot odds.  If they don't call your all in you still have their lead bet/raise.  If they are not going to lead out after a check then they are not likely to call an all in as the first bet anyway.

An all in before any bets is rarely a good play.